# Add two text messages/prompt messages on zxing barcode scanner

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, zxing

I have integrated zxing in my project. I need to display a message on the scanning activity. I've used `intent.putExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE","My custom text");` to display a message on the activity which is displayed at bottom of the layout. How can I display two messages on the layout. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure it is possible. How about using `\n`? `"My custom text1 \n custom text2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found Answer**

I modified the xml layout `capture.xml` of Zxing. Added another Textview in the layout as below.

```
<TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:text="Text 2"
        android:textColor="@color/status_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>`
```

I could display the text on top.

Comment: Hey there, can you please tell me where you've added / found / created this capture.xml . In my current project such a file didn't exist by default.

Answer (score 3):

For others, it might be interesting. Following steps allows to add text anywhere you want on the scanning layout of zxing.

1. Create an activity that extends from ***CaptureActivity***
2. Add the following code to the onCreate method

   ```
   public class ExtendedCaptureActivity extends CaptureActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
      TextView et = new TextView(this);
      et.setText("Veuillez scanner le code-barres comportant \nde 12 à 14 chiffres.");
       et.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
       et.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
       FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
           FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
       params.topMargin = 150;

       rootView.addView(et,params);

      }
   }
   ```
3. Call that intent to display the scanning activity.

Getting the root view of the the scanning activity, you can then add the view you want in it. Enjoy !